# Method Not Found ? This not made sense

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, methodnotfound

I'm trying to implement a FileUpload feature in a simple JSF/CDI project, with correct dependencies(i think) and the same code that i found in the primefaces showcase.

But for some reason, the FileUpload event does not found the listener in my ManagedBean.

I hope i can see something that i'm missing here, i already inspected the code a lot of times but i dont find anything that could be causing the problem.

My Xhtml page:

```
<html>
<h:head>
</h:head>

<body>
    <h:form>
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{file.uploadHandler()}"
            mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="messages"
            sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|txt)$/" />
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My ManagedBean:

```
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class File implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6644472075906217176L;
    private String fileName;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void uploadHandler(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Nome do Arquivo: " + event.getFile().getFileName());
    }
}
```

My pom.file :

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Console:

```
15:59:36,935 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-27) /index.xhtml @16,45 fileUploadListener="#{file.uploadHandler()}": Method not found: class timesheet.business.bean.File.uploadHandler(): javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @16,45 fileUploadListener="#{file.uploadHandler()}": Method not found: class timesheet.business.bean.File.uploadHandler()
```

Comment: Your method takes a parameter, but you're not passing one in your EL.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the method reference in `fileUpload` component

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{file.uploadHandler}"
```

Please note that there should be no **()** after the method name.